# importing contacts

Tags: civimail, contacts, joomla, import

I am trying to import 714 contacts to the system. I am able to do it but before the final DONE click it shows 445 total number of rows in the imported date and 1251 total number of contact records or modified during the import. 
it shows 28 duplicated rows, which I checked and that's correct.
But what about the difference in the numbers I am working with?

I hope you will be able to advice me on that.

Thanks,

Kanariya

Comment: Are you manipulating/creating relationships during the import? This will affect the number you are shown.

Comment: Hi, I am quite new to CRM and because there are no trainings available yet I'm trying to work out myself. Therefore I am not sure if I do manipulate or create a relationship during the import. Just follow the instructions. Is there any video you can send me to to be able to see exactly how it should happen? I wasn't able to find any. Thanks

Comment: Thats fine, most people do just try it without training. If your importing individuals and selecting an employer during the import then this will be an example of where relationships are created. You'll then see a higher number of contacts affected (up to double if every individual has an employer).